# Is it possible to use setTimout in Web Worker on ChromeCast

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, chromecast

I am trying to use JavaScripts WebWorkers and setTimeout to have a asynchronous Timeout on a ChromeCast Application.
This is used inside of jQuery, but the call to the asynch javascript file is outside of jQuery.

This is the minimal sample (without jquery and working standalone):

index html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<script>
    function func(){
        console.log("start");
        var worker = new Worker('timer.js'); //External script
        worker.onmessage = function(event) {    //Method called by external script
            console.log("10s later");

        };
    }
</script>
<body onload="func()">

</body>
</html>
```

timer.js:

```
setTimeout(continueExecution, 10000) //wait ten seconds before continuing
function continueExecution()
{
    postMessage(null);
}
```

the callback works inside the chromecast and jQuery, but is executed instantaneously without the delay of 10 seconds.

Does anyone know how the chromecast handles timeouts ?

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout does work on Chromecast, you can check out our [reference receiver](https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample/blob/master/player.js) which uses that method in multiple places.